# Using ImplicitRegion over variable number of dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation

I need code that creates a d-dimensional regions - where "d" varies. This simple example fails -

```
 d = 2
 aq = Array[q, d]
 dq = Sum[q[i]^2, {i, d}] < 7;
 Rq = ImplicitRegion[dq, aq];
 RegionMeasure[Rq]
```

but it works if the 4th line is

```
 Rq = ImplicitRegion[dq, {q[1], q[2]}];
```

Is there any way to avoid listing the variables?

Answer (score 5):

I am not certain this is going to work for your real problem.

```
d = 2;
dq = Sum[q[i]^2, {i, d}] < 7;
Rq = ImplicitRegion[dq, {q[1], q[2]}];
RegionMeasure[Rq]
```

returns 7 Pi

```
d = 2;
aq = Array[q, d];
dq = Sum[q[i]^2, {i, d}] < 7;
Rq = ImplicitRegion[dq, Evaluate[aq]];
RegionMeasure[Rq]
```

returns 7 Pi

Comment: Look at `Attributes[ImplicitRegion]` which shows the attribute `HoldAll`

Comment: Thanks Bill and Bob.  Great suggestions.